# ActionListener and button

Tags: java, actionlistener

I am having trouble with this java code.  I can't get my button to work, and when I adjust the button it doesn't recognize my variables (Test1, Test2, etc).  I've spent a good few hours on this and no matter what change I make I can't seem to get it right.  Any ideas?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

//Main class
public class gui12{
//Declare variables

public static void main (String args[]){



JFrame frame1;
Container pane;
JButton btnCalculate;
JLabel lblTest1,lblWeight1, lblWeight2, lblWeight3, lblWeight4,        lblTest2, lblTest3, lblTest4;
JTextField txtTest1, txtTest2, txtTest3, txtTest4,  txtWeight1, txtWeight2, txtWeight3, txtWeight4;  
Insets insets;
double Average;

    //Set Look and Feel
    try    {UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());}
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}
    catch (InstantiationException e) {}
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) {}
    catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {}

    //Create the frame
    frame1 = new JFrame ("Sample GUI Application");
    frame1.setSize (800,200);
    pane = frame1.getContentPane();
    insets = pane.getInsets();
    pane.setLayout (null);

    //Create controls
    btnCalculate = new JButton ("Calculate");
    lblTest1 = new JLabel ("Test1:");
    lblTest2 = new JLabel ("Test2");
    lblTest3 = new JLabel ("Test3");
    lblTest4 = new JLabel ("Test4");
  lblWeight1 = new JLabel ("Weight1");
  lblWeight2 = new JLabel ("Weight2");
  lblWeight3 = new JLabel ("Weight3");
  lblWeight4 = new JLabel ("Weight4");
    txtTest1 = new JTextField (5);
    txtTest2 = new JTextField  (5);
    txtTest3 = new JTextField  (5);
    txtWeight1 = new JTextField  (5);
  txtWeight2 = new JTextField (5);
    txtWeight3 = new JTextField  (5);
    txtWeight4 = new JTextField  (5);
  txtTest4 = new JTextField (5);



    //Add all components to panel
    pane.add (lblTest1);
    pane.add (lblTest2);
    pane.add (lblTest3);
    pane.add (lblTest4);
    pane.add (txtTest1);
    pane.add (txtTest2);
    pane.add (txtTest3);
    pane.add (txtTest4);
    pane.add (btnCalculate);
  pane.add (lblWeight1);
  pane.add (lblWeight2);
  pane.add (lblWeight3);
  pane.add (lblWeight4);
  pane.add (txtWeight1);
  pane.add (txtWeight2);
  pane.add (txtWeight3);
  pane.add (txtWeight4);

    //Place all components
    lblTest1.setBounds (insets.left + 5, insets.top + 5, lblTest1.getPreferredSize().width, lblTest1.getPreferredSize().height);
    txtTest1.setBounds (lblTest1.getX() + lblTest1.getWidth() + 5, insets.top + 5, txtTest1.getPreferredSize().width, txtTest1.getPreferredSize().height);
    lblTest2.setBounds (txtTest1.getX() + txtTest1.getWidth() + 8, insets.top + 5, lblTest2.getPreferredSize().width, lblTest2.getPreferredSize().height);
    txtTest2.setBounds (lblTest2.getX() + lblTest2.getWidth() + 8, insets.top + 5, txtTest2.getPreferredSize().width, txtTest2.getPreferredSize().height);
    lblTest3.setBounds (txtTest2.getX() + txtTest2.getWidth() + 5, insets.top + 5, lblTest3.getPreferredSize().width, lblTest3.getPreferredSize().height);
    txtTest3.setBounds (lblTest3.getX() + lblTest3.getWidth() + 5, insets.top + 5, txtTest3.getPreferredSize().width, txtTest3.getPreferredSize().height);
    lblTest4.setBounds (txtTest3.getX() + txtTest3.getWidth() + 5, insets.top + 5, lblTest4.getPreferredSize().width, lblTest4.getPreferredSize().height);
    txtTest4.setBounds (lblTest4.getX() + lblTest4.getWidth() + 5, insets.top + 5, txtTest4.getPreferredSize().width, txtTest4.getPreferredSize().height);
    btnCalculate.setBounds (txtTest4.getX() + txtTest4.getWidth() + 5, insets.top + 5, btnCalculate.getPreferredSize().width, btnCalculate.getPreferredSize().height);
    lblWeight1.setBounds (insets.left + 5, insets.top + 30, lblWeight1.getPreferredSize().width, lblWeight1.getPreferredSize().height);
    txtWeight1.setBounds (lblWeight1.getX() + lblWeight1.getWidth() + 5, insets.top + 30, txtWeight1.getPreferredSize().width, txtWeight1.getPreferredSize().height);
  lblWeight2.setBounds (txtWeight1.getX() + txtWeight1.getWidth() + 5, insets.top + 30, txtWeight1.getPreferredSize().width, txtWeight1.getPreferredSize().height);
   txtWeight2.setBounds (lblWeight2.getX() + lblWeight2.getWidth() + 10, insets.top + 30, txtWeight2.getPreferredSize().width, txtWeight2.getPreferredSize().height);
  lblWeight3.setBounds (txtWeight2.getX() + txtWeight2.getWidth() + 10, insets.top + 30, txtWeight2.getPreferredSize().width, txtWeight2.getPreferredSize().height);
   txtWeight3.setBounds (lblWeight3.getX() + lblWeight3.getWidth() + 10, insets.top + 30, txtWeight3.getPreferredSize().width, txtWeight3.getPreferredSize().height);
  lblWeight4.setBounds (txtWeight3.getX() + txtWeight3.getWidth() + 15, insets.top + 30, txtWeight4.getPreferredSize().width, txtWeight3.getPreferredSize().height);
   txtWeight4.setBounds (lblWeight4.getX() + lblWeight4.getWidth() + 15, insets.top + 30, txtWeight4.getPreferredSize().width, txtWeight4.getPreferredSize().height);

    //Set frame visible
    frame1.setVisible (true);

    //Button's action
    btnCalculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener()); //Register action
  double Test1 = Double.parseDouble(txtTest1.getText());
  double Test2 = Double.parseDouble(txtTest2.getText());
  double Test3 = Double.parseDouble(txtTest3.getText());
  double Test4 = Double.parseDouble(txtTest4.getText());
  double Weight1 = Double.parseDouble (txtWeight1.getText());
  double Weight2 = Double.parseDouble(txtWeight2.getText());
  double Weight3 = Double.parseDouble (txtWeight3.getText());
  double Weight4 = Double.parseDouble(txtWeight4.getText());
  }

  public class btnCalculate implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
        Average = ((Test1*Weight1)+(Test2*Weight2)+(Test3*Weight3)+(Test4*Weight4));
        Average = ((Test1*Weight1)+(Test2*Weight2)+(Test3*Weight3)+(Test4*Weight4));

     System.out.println(Average);

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your actionPerformed() method next to the listener constructor, like this:

```
btnCalculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
        Average = ((Test1*Weight1)+(Test2*Weight2)+(Test3*Weight3)+(Test4*Weight4));
    } 
} );
```

Your current code is creating a new **class** called btnCalculate that is not being used. You want to assign a listener to the **Jbutton object** btnCalculate.

Alternatively, I believe you could write:

```
btnCalculate.addActionListener(new btnCalculate());
```

However, this is bad form since you use the same name to refer to two separate entities.

Comment: but his variables are not final, did you test this?

Answer (score 0):

your variables are not static you cannot call the outside the main method, you cannot simply call the constructor of an interface, you must override wherever you do call it, so delete that class and add this where you new ActionListener() is.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    JFrame frame1;
    Container pane;
    JButton btnCalculate;
    JLabel lblTest1, lblWeight1, lblWeight2, lblWeight3, lblWeight4, lblTest2, lblTest3, lblTest4;
    JTextField txtTest1, txtTest2, txtTest3, txtTest4, txtWeight1, txtWeight2, txtWeight3, txtWeight4;
    Insets insets;
    double Average;

    //Set Look and Feel
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
    }
    //Create the frame
    frame1 = new JFrame("Sample GUI Application");
    frame1.setSize(800, 200);
    pane = frame1.getContentPane();
    insets = pane.getInsets();
    pane.setLayout(null);

    //Create controls
    btnCalculate = new JButton("Calculate");
    lblTest1 = new JLabel("Test1:");
    lblTest2 = new JLabel("Test2");
    lblTest3 = new JLabel("Test3");
    lblTest4 = new JLabel("Test4");
    lblWeight1 = new JLabel("Weight1");
    lblWeight2 = new JLabel("Weight2");
    lblWeight3 = new JLabel("Weight3");
    lblWeight4 = new JLabel("Weight4");
    txtTest1 = new JTextField(5);
    txtTest2 = new JTextField(5);
    txtTest3 = new JTextField(5);
    txtWeight1 = new JTextField(5);
    txtWeight2 = new JTextField(5);
    txtWeight3 = new JTextField(5);
    txtWeight4 = new JTextField(5);
    txtTest4 = new JTextField(5);

    //Add all components to panel
    pane.add(lblTest1);
    pane.add(lblTest2);
    pane.add(lblTest3);
    pane.add(lblTest4);
    pane.add(txtTest1);
    pane.add(txtTest2);
    pane.add(txtTest3);
    pane.add(txtTest4);
    pane.add(btnCalculate);
    pane.add(lblWeight1);
    pane.add(lblWeight2);
    pane.add(lblWeight3);
    pane.add(lblWeight4);
    pane.add(txtWeight1);
    pane.add(txtWeight2);
    pane.add(txtWeight3);
    pane.add(txtWeight4);

    //Place all components
    lblTest1.setBounds(insets.left + 5, insets.top + 5, lblTest1.getPreferredSize().width, lblTest1.getPreferredSize().height);
    txtTest1.setBounds(lblTest1.getX() + lblTest1.getWidth() + 5, insets.top + 5, txtTest1.getPreferredSize().width, txtTest1.getPreferredSize().height);
    lblTest2.setBounds(txtTest1.getX() + txtTest1.getWidth() + 8, insets.top + 5, lblTest2.getPreferredSize().width, lblTest2.getPreferredSize().height);
    txtTest2.setBounds(lblTest2.getX() + lblTest2.getWidth() + 8, insets.top + 5, txtTest2.getPreferredSize().width, txtTest2.getPreferredSize().height);
    lblTest3.setBounds(txtTest2.getX() + txtTest2.getWidth() + 5, insets.top + 5, lblTest3.getPreferredSize().width, lblTest3.getPreferredSize().height);
    txtTest3.setBounds(lblTest3.getX() + lblTest3.getWidth() + 5, insets.top + 5, txtTest3.getPreferredSize().width, txtTest3.getPreferredSize().height);
    lblTest4.setBounds(txtTest3.getX() + txtTest3.getWidth() + 5, insets.top + 5, lblTest4.getPreferredSize().width, lblTest4.getPreferredSize().height);
    txtTest4.setBounds(lblTest4.getX() + lblTest4.getWidth() + 5, insets.top + 5, txtTest4.getPreferredSize().width, txtTest4.getPreferredSize().height);
    btnCalculate.setBounds(txtTest4.getX() + txtTest4.getWidth() + 5, insets.top + 5, btnCalculate.getPreferredSize().width, btnCalculate.getPreferredSize().height);
    lblWeight1.setBounds(insets.left + 5, insets.top + 30, lblWeight1.getPreferredSize().width, lblWeight1.getPreferredSize().height);
    txtWeight1.setBounds(lblWeight1.getX() + lblWeight1.getWidth() + 5, insets.top + 30, txtWeight1.getPreferredSize().width, txtWeight1.getPreferredSize().height);
    lblWeight2.setBounds(txtWeight1.getX() + txtWeight1.getWidth() + 5, insets.top + 30, txtWeight1.getPreferredSize().width, txtWeight1.getPreferredSize().height);
    txtWeight2.setBounds(lblWeight2.getX() + lblWeight2.getWidth() + 10, insets.top + 30, txtWeight2.getPreferredSize().width, txtWeight2.getPreferredSize().height);
    lblWeight3.setBounds(txtWeight2.getX() + txtWeight2.getWidth() + 10, insets.top + 30, txtWeight2.getPreferredSize().width, txtWeight2.getPreferredSize().height);
    txtWeight3.setBounds(lblWeight3.getX() + lblWeight3.getWidth() + 10, insets.top + 30, txtWeight3.getPreferredSize().width, txtWeight3.getPreferredSize().height);
    lblWeight4.setBounds(txtWeight3.getX() + txtWeight3.getWidth() + 15, insets.top + 30, txtWeight4.getPreferredSize().width, txtWeight3.getPreferredSize().height);
    txtWeight4.setBounds(lblWeight4.getX() + lblWeight4.getWidth() + 15, insets.top + 30, txtWeight4.getPreferredSize().width, txtWeight4.getPreferredSize().height);

    //Set frame visible
    frame1.setVisible(true);

    //Button's action
    btnCalculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // you won't have access to your variables here unless they are final, because this is an inner class, I sugest you do not make a gui inside the static main.
        }
    }); //Register action
    double Test1 = Double.parseDouble(txtTest1.getText());
    double Test2 = Double.parseDouble(txtTest2.getText());
    double Test3 = Double.parseDouble(txtTest3.getText());
    double Test4 = Double.parseDouble(txtTest4.getText());
    double Weight1 = Double.parseDouble(txtWeight1.getText());
    double Weight2 = Double.parseDouble(txtWeight2.getText());
    double Weight3 = Double.parseDouble(txtWeight3.getText());
    double Weight4 = Double.parseDouble(txtWeight4.getText());
}
```

don't forget the basic rules of the static modifier, and interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Sean Scott said.

First, argument of addActionListener() should be inner class implementing ActionListner. 
Also you shouldn't give the same name to variable and class at the same time.

```
btnCalculate.addActionListener(new btnCalculate()) // Again, you shouldn't name inner class the same way as JButton variable...
```